# fitty.js only applying to first class element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a fading slideshow of images which play on loop.
Each image also has a caption with it that I have applied fitty.js in order to fit each caption to the width of the container.

I'm struggling to work out why only the first .line element is being effected by fitty.js
I have removed the each element of the jQuery individually and narrowed the issue down to how I'm hiding the .carousel-cell elements to start with.

What I'm trying to achieve is that, when you land of the page all of the .carousel-cell elements are hidden apart from the first one. They should then fade in and fade out on loop indefinitely.

Here's the jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  fitty('.line');
});


$('.carousel-cell').hide();
$('.carousel-cell:first').show();


setInterval(function() {
  $('.carousel-cell:first')
    .fadeOut(0)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(0)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}, 1000);
```

And here's the html...

```
<div id="slideshow">
      <div class="carousel-cell">
        <img src="https://mrlondoner.com/couch/uploads/image/pall_mall.png" />
        <div class="line"><h1>soho</h1></div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">
        <img src="https://mrlondoner.com/couch/uploads/image/tower_bridge.png" />
        <div class="line"><h1>tower bridge</h1></div>
      </div>     
</div>
```

Fiddle link below...
https://jsfiddle.net/spittman/nv2e3czj/39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fitty is having issues resizing as it parent element's visibility is impacted due to carousel.

Either refactor your code to keep track of the element number it is iterating though so you can call a refit on a specific element

or

Be lazy-ish and just call the fitAll() function when your carousel item moves to the next and parent element is visible. ex:

```
setInterval(function() {
 var wee = $('.carousel-cell:first')
.fadeOut(0)
.next()
.fadeIn(0)
.end()
.appendTo('#slideshow');
fitty.fitAll();
}, 1000);
```